# How can I allow the access to the microphone to Google Voice on Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, audio, microphone

I use [Google Voice](https://voice.google.com/u/0/) on Chrome 117 on Windows 10. I am trying to make a call. Google Voice says I need to "allow mic access" in Chrome, which I thought I already did. How can I allow the access to the microphone to Google Voice on Chrome?

---

Screenshots below.

Google Voice says I need to "allow mic access" in Chrome:

[image]

I had already allowed mic access as follows:

[image]

[image]

Did I miss something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message from Google Voice was misleading. Google Voice says I need to "allow mic access" in Chrome, but in fact the issue was simply that the microphone was unplugged. I was able to understand that when switching to Firefox and seeing that my microphone wasn't listed by Google Voice there.